# Is there a way to view summary of only 1 item (not all of them) in a google form?

Tags: google-forms

Regular google-form-summary publishes a summary of **all** questions in the form.
In my form I collect e-mail addresses (as one of the questions) and I would not like to view them in a public summary. Does anyone know how to do this?